# Set cookie path and cookie domain in Magento for multi store

Tags: multistore, login, cookie

I've seen a ton of posts out there regarding issue, but no resolution yet.

Trying to set a cookie path and cookie domain for a multi-store Magento setup for the 2 stores I have in Magento (ver. 1.9.2.4).

1. mystore.com
2. retail.mystore.com

I've set main store (mystore.com) config to

```
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: mystore.com
```

And I've set retail store (retail.mystore.com) config to

```
Cookie Path: / 
Cookie Domain: retail.mystore.com
```

Need to set a different cookie for each. Any idea what I'm missing?

**UPDATED ANSWER**
I resolved by setting main store

```
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: mystore.com
```

and retail store as

```
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: .mystore.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use below thing for both the stores.

```
cookie path : '/'
cookie domain : '.mystore.com'
```

Comment: I was able to resolve. I included my answer above.